# Python static class variable and import modules

Tags: python, static-members, python-import

I tried to write the most simple example, the behavior of which I do not understand:

File `Main.py`

```
import Module

class Main:
    st = 1
    def __init__(self):
        Main.st = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Module.Test() # prints 1
    m = Main()
    Module.Test() # prints 1
```

File `Module.py`

```
import Main

def Test():
    print(Main.Main.st)
```

File `Test.py`

```
import Main
import Module

Module.Test() # prints 1
m = Main.Main()
Module.Test() # prints 2
```

If I run the `Test.py` I get an answer (one, two) which is expected to receive. But if I run the `Main.py` I get a different answer (one, one). And I do not understand why it happens.

Comment: You have circular import: `Main->Module->Main`

Comment: Note that Python runs the initial script as the `__main__` module, so it gets a **separate** namespace from `Main`.

Comment: @shx2: no, the import runs `__main__` -> `Module` -> `Main`.